# Executing testNG from command line with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, selenium, batch-file, encoding

This may be a Java question. 
I have a simple batch file that executes testNG xml (A test suite for selenium tests)as below.

```
java -cp D:\..\..\lib\*;D:\..\..\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
pause
```

Tests are executed on Japanese application , which at times deals with Japanese characters.
When I execute it from Eclipse , there is no problem. But when I execute same tests from batch file , tests fail giving exception

> Unable to locate element :<"method":"link text","selector":"?????">

I know that there is *-Dfile.encoding=utf-8* option with java, but I am not sure how I can incorporate that in above batch file.

Comment: Did you try adding it to the java command? `java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -cp .......`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes I already did . But it is not working.

Comment: See what command eclipse is executing. Breakpoint your code and run `ps aux | grep -i java` and get the command eclipse is executing

Comment: @TarunLalwani : I think ps aux grep command is for linux. I am using batch file , which only runs on windows. Thanks for giving me idea though , I can figure out with equivalent command in windows.

Comment: Yes, the thought process is to figure out the command line used by Eclipse and use the same in the batch file